# Do one-gang power outlets with more than two jacks exist?

Tags: receptacle, gfci, product-recommendation, usa

There is a GFCI-power outlet in an awkward place, where we really need *three* devices plugged-in. The location makes use of an extender and power-strip undesirable.

There is a variety of *expanders* on the market, but, because the existing outlet is a GFCI, the expanders cannot be secured to it with the long bolt included with them.

So, *ideally*, I'd replace the existing dual outlet with a triple one -- except, I cannot find any! It would seem, it should be possible to squeeze three jacks into the one-gang volume, but no one is offering it. Is it, perhaps, against the law and/or code? I wouldn't mind it protruding outside -- like those expanders do -- but it needs to offer the GFCI safety.

Comment: What exactly you're trying to plug in could change the answers. For example: if one of those things is something like a phone charger, a duplex outlet with USB ports could solve your problem.

Comment: For low-power applications, especially for multiple wall-wart PSUs, I'm a fan of 6-inch daisy-chainable extension cords.  If this is of interest I'll add an answer.

Comment: @bta, we'd like to have the coffee-maker and the toaster plugged-in at all times, and still have an outlet free for things like hand-mixer...

Comment: @MikhailT. What are the current and/or power ratings of the coffee maker and toaster? What is the power rating of whatever other device you might want to plug in?

Comment: IF it's for a toaster and coffee maker, why can't you use a high quality power bar plugged in to a standard GFCI?  The bar will sit on the counter behind the appliances and nobody will see it.  One wall socket and several more on the bar will be available.  The bar's breaker will pop if you use both appliances at once, which is great b/c you don't have to run to the basement.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the loads on the circuit are within the circuit rating and the loads on the outlet are within the outlet rating.   It is unlawful to make the test/reset buttons inaccessible, as they do need to be tested according to instructions (follow instructions: NEC 110.3).

First, I have no opinion of those screw-on expander plates, as we had one spectacularly burn up due to poor contact. It was UL Listed. If one is actively smoking, there's no way to pull it off to a) de-energize it and b) put it in a non-flammable basket, sink or tub - **because, y'know, *it's screwed down***. Fortunately, we hadn't bothered, and unplugging it ended the "event".

### A plain outlet with "GFCI Protected" sticker

99% of the time when a consumer sees a GFCI device, they see a GFCI receptacle. That's because consumers don't spend a lot of time gazing at electrical panels, or studying odd little boxes that have no sockets. As such, they associate "GFCI" with "receptacle".

But a GFCI is not that at all. Really, that thing is a "combo device" containing both a GFCI *and two sockets*.  A GFCI is just a "lump in the line" that contains some sensors and an interruptable relay/contactor. Sorta like [something else :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)

[image]

*Note that ground doesn't even connect to the GFCI.  On a GFCI "receptacle", ground only serves the sockets, which you have to imagine are fed by brown/gray.*

So what does this mean?  Look at the "LOAD" wires (brown/grey here). **We can feed plain sockets from that**, and they will be GFCI-protected, just the same.   So you can simply follow that circuit back to the panel, and find either another receptacle between there and the panel (and put the GFCI there), find a new place to put one that's legally wire-able, or simply use a GFCI *circuit breaker*.

If the circuit is required to be dedicated to that room (kitchen, bathroom countertop, or the mandatory 20A circuit to laundry or garage), then adding a receptacle elsewhere is illegal, but you can always use [a deadfront](https://www.howtolookatahouse.com/Blog/Entries/2019/10/what-is-a-dead-front-gfci-or-blank-face-gfci-1.html).

### Or a simpler adapter.

You should be able to use a 3-way electrical splitter on either or both sockets.  These come either in linear or T-format, the latter helpful for "wall warts". Note these are not necessarily tamper-resistant.

You will need to remove them to test and reset the GFCI, but you should *anyway* if you have a need to reset the GFCI.

[image]

### Wait. Did you say *kitchen?*  That is a huge X-factor.

Sorry, I missed this. Kitchen loads are big.  In Europe, where they don't have our kin of limits, a 2500 watt random kitchen appliance is common.  Here, due to our 120V fixation and UL rules, we are cornered at 1500W, and most appliances push that to the absolute limit *because they have to, to get the job done*  As things are, the old kitchen 15A (1800W) circuits or new, mandatory 20A (2400W) circuits cannot support 2 at once, except for things like 2-slice toasters (typically 750W so design changes aren't required for 4-slice toasters).

The nameplates on the equipment will tell the amps or VA or watts required.  Divide by 120 to get amps.

In our incident, yes, it was in the kitchen, but we were well aware of the amp limits - my sweetie understands the ["counting amps"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGPMadwqPKQ) thing* and we weren't even running 2 appliances at once. Just one heat making appliance at <=1500W did the number on our splitter. This was a UL-listed no-name unit off QVC. This is just typical of the poor quality of screw-on splitters - they are intended for inkjet printers and cable TV boxes, not toasters and coffee makers.

These splitters attach to only one socket (because MWBCs exist with 240V across the two socket's hots). The NEMA 5-15 is a 15A socket, not rated for 20A on one socket.

Our plan, when I get a Round Tuit, is to blow that receptacle out to 2-3 gang, and install 1-2 plain receps fed off a GFCI.

---

* Note the Green Acres episode is obsolete; refrigerators are actually the smallest load in your kitchen, drawing only a "1" (sorry 1 amp) when they're even running, or maybe 3 on defrost cycle.

Comment: The common problem with these unsecured expanders is that unplugging one cord from them often results in the entire expander falling out, disconnecting all other devices too. Given that this is a kitchen, it may fall out into a puddle of water (such as from the freshly-washed dishes), further complicating matters... This is why my preferred solution would be securely fastened to (or even _into_) the wall...

Comment: @MikhailT. The ones I linked fill only 1 socket hole, leaving the other free for your occasional swap.  It sounds like you're being very nitpicky/standing on perfection, which is fine, but you're talking kitchen - huge loads, no margin for cheapness.  So yeah, you have zero safe options *except* blowing out the 1-gang box into 2-3 gang and using proper sockets. Sorry, I know you probably don't want to hear that.

Answer (score 6):

<s>I don't think you will find *any* triple receptacles in a single gang.</s> I am almost 100% sure you will not find a triple *with GFCI*, because that is just too much to stuff in a single gang.

You have two main options:

- Expand the box

If this is in a typical hollow wall (e.g., drywall over studs), you can remove the existing box, make the hole bigger and install a larger box with two sets of receptacles - the existing GFCI/receptacle plus a second duplex receptacle next to it and connected to the *LOAD* terminals of the GFCI.

- Move the GFCI

GFCI protection does *not* have to be at point of use. It can be at the breaker (generally more expensive than GFCI/receptacle), at any previous receptacle in the circuit or added as a "deadfront" - a GFCI which is *only* a GFCI, no receptacles included. If this is a kitchen countertop or bathroom receptacle then any additional receptacles must be in that room, but a deadfront or breaker would still be just fine. Then you can replace the GFCI/receptacle with a standard, non-Decora, duplex receptacle and attach an extender.

Important concern: *awkward place* + *electrical splitter* can be a bit of a problem. The extenders that screw in using the screw in the middle of a traditional duplex receptacle (as opposed to Decora style) are pretty secure. The splitters that plug into a single receptacle without blocking the middle are really just hanging around. I have seen them get a bit burnt up due to bad connections as they get loose over time. As a temporary fix they are great, but they usually end up becoming effectively permanent. When they are easily accessible that is usually not a big deal - they don't suddenly melt down (usually) and they can be pushed back in place easily until they no longer hold and then replaced very inexpensively. But if they are in an awkward place with a few appliances effectively permanently plugged in, any issues may *not* be noticed until it is too late. Which I suspect is why OP was talking about a screw-in extender (much more secure/reliable) and why I am suggesting, despite the cost and work involved, changing the receptacle in some way rather than just sticking something into it.

Comment: Depends on the location.  Expanders with outlets on the side can be very nice behind furniture.